# How to access Jenkins git-changelog plugin output using java?

Tags: java, git, jenkins, changelog

I want to get list of commit Id's shown in Git Changelog Plugin output as post-build action and iterate through it using java. Which script/method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

With a Pipeline you can have the plugin return its context. And then loop through it. This works with plugin version 2.0 and later. In this example I list all commit id:s between develop and master. But you can specify `type: 'COMMIT'` and specific commit if that is what you want.

```
node {
 sh """
 git clone git@github.com:jenkinsci/git-changelog-plugin.git .
 """

 def changelogContext = gitChangelog returnType: 'CONTEXT',
  from: [type: 'REF', value: 'master'],
  to: [type: 'REF', value: 'develop']

 changelogContext.commits.each { commit ->
  println "Commit id: ${commit.hashFull}"
 }
}
```

If you want to do this in pure Java, not a Pipeline. You can just use [the lib](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib).